# Ruby: Trouble creating data in a yaml file

Tags: ruby

How to organize data in my yml file in a way that when I need them I can access  x=>1, y=>1, and z=>2 from it.

I want to write "1" only once.

Comment: Could you expand your question? A lot? What is `x` and `y`, `a`, `z`, `c`, if they are variables? If they are not variables, it is not correct Ruby, so it is somewhat hard to know what you mean. Also, if you mean what I think you mean, the only way not to reuse the key `a` would be if `y` was a reference to `x`, which is probably not what you want. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: x, y and z are variable. a and c are values like a is 1 and c is 2.

Comment: So x=>1, y=>1 and z=>2

Comment: I feel like there's something that's not getting across here. Why couldn't you just do `YAML.dump({x => a, y => a, z => c})`?

Comment: Do you mean `{ "x" => 1, "y" => 1, "z" => 2 }` or maybe `{ :x => 1, :y => 1, :z => 2 }`? If not, then I still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = <<YAML
---
:x: &a 1
:y: *a
:z: 2
YAML

puts YAML.load(yaml)
# => {:x=>1, :y=>1, :z=>2}
```

From YAML specification:

> 3.2.2.2. Anchors and Aliases
>
> In the representation graph, a node may appear in more than one collection. When serializing such data, the first occurrence of the node is identified by an anchor. Each subsequent occurrence is serialized as an alias node which refers back to this anchor. Otherwise, anchor names are a serialization detail and are discarded once composing is completed. When composing a representation graph from serialized events, an alias node refers to the most recent node in the serialization having the specified anchor. Therefore, anchors need not be unique within a serialization. In addition, an anchor need not have an alias node referring to it. It is therefore possible to provide an anchor for all nodes in serialization.

Here, `&a` is an anchor for the value under the `:x` key; `*a` is an alias that makes the `:y` key's value to be the same object.

Comment: It would probably be good to explain what this construct is (i.e. references and anchors).